# DOCZ : You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, components, react-component

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFByZ.png

Getting the error like, Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. while running docz(React component documentation tool)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have a webpack loader configured to handle CSS files. Either your project doesn't typically use CSS for styles and is using something like SCSS instead, or you just need to configure a loader for CSS.

[css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) is a popular webpack loader for css.